# Not able to send Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

```
string from = "myemail@gmail.com";
string to = "other.mail.123@gmail.com";

System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(to);
mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from, "One Ghost", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
mail.Subject = "This is a test mail";
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.Body = "This is Email Body Text";
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "XXXXX");
client.Port = 587; 
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true; 
try
{
    client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Exception ex2 = ex;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("errroorr " + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Its throwing an exception at client.send() method. It says message sending failed.What might be the problem
inner exception is this

inner exception says      `System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.141.109:587 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)`

Comment: set ssl to false and try sending.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Can you post the *full* error message (i.e. the output of `ex.ToString()`).

Comment: 74.125.141.109:587 -> is it the correct server? Is it open for smtp traffic, firewall problem?

Comment: `because the target machine actively refused it` means the port is closed (not firewalled as hidden). I suspect the machine at 74.125.141.109 port 587 is not running an SMTP server. [This Google help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1668960&page=ts.cs&from=184972&rd=1) suggests port 465 using SSL.

Comment: The inner exception has all the information you need: your SMTP server actively refused the connection. This is not a coding error, you should get back to your email provider and get the appropriate connection settings (TLS options, required credentials etc)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I changed the port to 465 and now it shows this error       System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at MailMessage.WebForm1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\adkas\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\MailMessage\MailMessage\WebForm1.aspx.cs:line 47

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these two settings

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

also check if you have an antivirus on your server that is blocking send email request

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this it's below

```
public static void SendMail(string Message, string Subject)
    {
        bool retVal;
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        MailAddress fromAddres = new MailAddress(FromMail, "Test");
        message.From = fromAddres;
        // To address collection of MailAddress
        message.To.Add(ToMail);
        message.Subject = Subject;
        smtpClient.Host = HotName;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SmtpUser, SmtpPassword);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // Message body content
        message.Body = Message;    

        smtpClient.Send(message);

        retVal = true;
        message.Dispose();
    }
```

i think this will help you........

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting it as an answer, i intended it to b a reply to the original post.

SMTP will require credentials, I didn't find the credentials being supplied.
Try  `telnet` to connect to server. If the port is accessible and if you have the SMTP credentials, you will be able to send an email from the command line itself.

Try this and let me know whether that works for you or not.

Comment: Hi, [try this](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html) or [msdn link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx) or [google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=smtp+telnet&oq=smtp+telnet&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)